# No rule to make (phony) target

Tags: makefile

I am trying to create a pattern rule for a phony target `foo-test` which should build an actual file `foo-test1`:

```
%-test: %-test1

%-test1:
    touch $@
```

When I call `make --just-print foo-test` I get `No rule to make target: foo-test`.

Yet I would expect make to see that `foo-test` depends on `foo-test1` and apply the second rule to make `foo-test1`. How can achieve this behaviour? (I have tried declaring `%-test` and `%-test1` as `.PHONY`; it doesn't help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
%-test: %-test1
```

does not define a pattern rule.  It *deletes* a pattern rule.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html

You have to give it a recipe if you want to make a pattern rule.  Something like this is sufficient:

```
%-test: %-test1 ;
```

Comment: Ah :) but now when I run it does `touch foo-test1` then `rm foo-test1`; how to stop it deleting?

Comment: It's an intermediate file.  See discussion in https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html

Comment: Aha - `.SECONDARY:` with no targets tells make never to throw anything away :)